# How do I enable this timer in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, sequence

I've started a course of c# and I cant get my timer to run. Its probably pretty simple and I've just missed something here. Basically I have a button to start and stop a traffic light sequence. I wanted an interval of 1 second. Heres what I've written. It doesn't work as intended when I press start. Thank  you.

```
 }
    public int counter = 0;

private void rbStart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    counter++;

    if (counter == 1)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = true;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (counter == 2)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = true;
        pbAmber.Visible = true;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (counter == 3)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = false;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (counter == 4)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = false;
        pbAmber.Visible = true;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (counter == 5)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = true;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
}

private void rbStop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    pbRed.Visible = false;
    pbAmber.Visible = false;
    pbGreen.Visible = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Light_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(rbStart_CheckedChanged);
    Light_timer.Interval = 1000;

}
```

}

Comment: you haven't provided an interval for the timer yet, or have you? show that portion too where you initialize the timer

Comment: what exactly doesnt go as intended then? provide more detail if you can

Comment: In addition to nawfal's comment, I would also move the event handler assignment outside the event handler. I am surprise that this is not recursive, causing a stack overflow.

Comment: The timer does not count when the sequence begins. Its always at 1000. I selected the interval in the properties so I didnt write it in the code. Thanks for the fast responses and patience. Im only a beginner :) –

Answer (score 0):

The Interval property merely designates how much time elapses between Tick events. You might want to consider a separate variable to track the "state" of your light, and then "bump" that variable with each "Tick" in your event handler. Then just adjust your UI elements to reflect the proper state of your traffic light. You might have a "stopped" state, a "careful" state, and a "green" state, and your light might just "cycle" between each on on each tick. I'll leave you to write the details as it appears to be an assignment. Good luck.

Comment: Its just a simple program Im supposed to write as build up to the end of module assignment. Its not a big deal at this point I'm shown by someone else how to get it working tbh. The lecturer will explain it to me on monday if I cant get help here :)

Comment: Okay. A few things...First, the Interval property and the Tick event handler assignment need to go elsewhere, such as in your form's Load event. You don't have to perpetually reassign the handler - just do it once, and the handler will fire after evern "Interval" milliseconds has passed. So, if you set "Interval" to 3000, the Tick event (and thus your handler) will fire every 3 seconds. Your "state tracking" variable should be a form-level variables, and you should bump it each time your event handler fires, resetting it to a "start" value if it goes beyond the # of states your light has...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had nother go tonight. Im still a little stuck. The sequence does not run at 1 second intervals. It runs extremely fast. When I use break point though it runs through the code perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably misinterpreted how the Timer works. The [Timer.Tick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) fires when the Interval has elapsed. Interval is used by the Timer to determine how long to run between ticks. Its value is never changed by the Timer. In fact, a System.Windows.Forms.Timer has no way to retrieve elapsed time, which means you'll need a state tracking mechanism of your own that doesn't depend on that. Take a good look at the example on the page I referenced above and make sure you understand how it works, then give it another shot.

Comment: Sorry Im still having trouble. What would you correct this to? What Ive shown here is the code for the 2 buttons.