# Getting this timer to work in C# (newbie)

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable this timer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755115/how-do-i-enable-this-timer-in-c)

Im trying to get a little project running. When I use a break point it goes through the code correctly, but when running the program at normal speed it the sequence runs too fast. Im trying to get the traffic lights sequence to change every 1 second. What is wrong with this code? Its a simple sequence of traffic lights, incase your interested :). Newbie project.

```
    }
        public int counter = 0;

    private void rbStart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Light_timer.Start();
        counter++;

        if (counter == 1)
        {
            pbRed.Visible = true;
            pbAmber.Visible = false;
            pbGreen.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (counter == 2)
        {
            pbRed.Visible = true;
            pbAmber.Visible = true;
            pbGreen.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (counter == 3)
        {
            pbRed.Visible = false;
            pbAmber.Visible = false;
            pbGreen.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (counter == 4)
        {
            pbRed.Visible = false;
            pbAmber.Visible = true;
            pbGreen.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (counter == 5)
        {
            pbRed.Visible = true;
            pbAmber.Visible = false;
            pbGreen.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    private void rbStop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pbRed.Visible = false;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Light_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(rbStart_CheckedChanged);
        Light_timer.Interval = 1000;
        Light_timer.Stop();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: yes sorry Im new. I had another look at it tonight and think ive got some where. i didnt know to edit my old post.

Comment: There are certainly a couple glitches here, but running too fast doesn't appear to be one of them.  What is the timer 'tick' event bound to in the designer?  maybe it's being called twice.

Comment: You solved my problem. The tick was bound to something else in the designer. I must have done it early on. The code works as I intended now :). Out of curiosity what glitches did you notice that I could improve?

Comment: When you click stop (rbStop?), you should stop your timer.  Your red signal lasts 3 seconds (counter value 6 ,1 and 5).  It might be more elegant to put your timer tick code in its own method.

Answer (score 3):

You're hooking up the event handler every time the timer elapses and so on... Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Light_timer = new Timer();
    Light_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerElapsed);
    Light_timer.Interval = 1000;
}

private void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;

    if (counter == 1)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = true;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (counter == 2)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = true;
        pbAmber.Visible = true;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (counter == 3)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = false;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (counter == 4)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = false;
        pbAmber.Visible = true;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (counter == 5)
    {
        pbRed.Visible = true;
        pbAmber.Visible = false;
        pbGreen.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = 0;
        Light_timer.Stop();
    }
}

private void rbStart_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Light_timer.Start();
}

private void rbStop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Light_timer.Stop();
    pbRed.Visible = false;
    pbAmber.Visible = false;
    pbGreen.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Even though I got mine working that is much tidier code. Thank you Michael. :)